# Can I Decrypt Encrypted String using Different Application

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences, android-keystore

I'm using Android keystore to encrypt sensitive information, and save the encrypted string and IV in SharedPreference. But is it safe? If someone get the encrypted string and IV, can they decrypt it?

Comment: The IV is not meant to be secret. You still need the *key* for decryption.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart can others get the key? or generate the key using other application?

Comment: If they could, then encryption would be kind of *pointless*, don't you think?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm newbie in encryption. Just want to make sure how safe is android-keystore encryption :)